# How to avoid a reflow when changing box-shadow or text-shadow properties?

Tags: css, browser, hover, reflow

This is my test css:

```
.btn {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}
```

Applied to a simple div with the "btn" class. Using Firefox's 28 Web Developer Console I discovered that 1 reflow is executed every time the mouse goes hover the div, and another reflow is executed when the mouse is no more hover the div.

If I change the "position" property from "relative" to "absolute" nothing changes, neither if I deactivate the "text-shadow" or the "box-shadow" property. The only way that I've found that doesn't trigger the two reflows is by disablig both the "box-shadow" and the "text-shadow" properties.

Why is this happening and how I can avoid the execution of the two reflows?

Comment: For potential answers: Using default transparent shadow apparently does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/RkceR/3/show/

Comment: By reflow you mean moving the position of the button? I think it happens because of adding the shadow to the width of the button. Does the background of the button have a solid color? If yes, let's say white, how about adding a white border/shadow with the same width to the image on non-hover, and changing it to your desired shadow on hover?

Comment: I don't observe any reflow events (Firefox 36.0.4)
https://jsfiddle.net/gkahu1cd/